# cPanel - MariaDB - Update field in multiples databases

Tags: shell, mariadb, cpanel, code-snippets

We have a cPanel account with several databases.

Some of these databases have a common field, type text, as a snippet.

One of these databases is the MASTER. What we would like to do is to update this field in 1 table of our MASTER databases and update the same value in the rest of the databases. In all databases, the name of the table and the field is the same.

We have tried doing this connecting to DB by shell script for having the new value and later try to update the rest of the databases. When que save the value of the field, it doesn't safe the right value.

In an example:

FILE query.txt

> ```
> SELECT snippet FROM wp_hfcm_scripts where snippet like '%myvalue%';
> ```

**If we connect DB and run, then ok:**

> ```
> mysql -D mybbdd Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MariaDB connection id is 941167 Server version:
> 10.3.25-MariaDB MariaDB Server
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> MariaDB [mybbdd]> SELECT snippet FROM wp_hfcm_scripts where snippet like '%myvalue%';
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | 
> <script>  //myvalue 20201007
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function($){ . . .
> ```

**But if we directly launch the query in the command line, then it responds with a strange format:**

> ```
> mysql -D mybbdd < query.sql
> snippet
> \n\t\tjQuery("#hero-responsive > p, #hero-responsive > br, #info-responsive > p, #info-responsive > br, #checkout-responsive > p, #checkout-responsive > br, #right-checkout-responsive > p, #er\n    \t\t\tjQuery(element).append("<div class='video-checkout'><div
> ```
>
> class=''><div
> .
> .
> .

Does anyone know why this may be happening?